# Do not allow access with simple ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

How do I have to set my routes in a way that pages can not be accessed anymore with simple ids, but only with `friendly_ids`?

I do not want that people are able to access a certain page just entering the id of the object.

EXAMPLE:

I do want to access a model only like this:

`example.com/model/slug`

But it should not be possible to access it like this:

`example.com/model/id`

Comment: This question is unclear. Provide some code and tell us the problem including the errors.

Comment: @MHakvoort I added an example. It does not create an error, it's just a safety measure I would like to implement.